# How to reduce the Apk size in Unity for Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I Put a video in asset folder with the size of 4mb, so its getting 200Mb size of APK. Is there any chance to Compress apk file?

Actually, I dont want to decrease the quality of video and is there any chance to put the data in cloud and import in unityhub? is it help me to decrease the size of apk?

Comment: Unity uses its own compression methods, check the import window for changing the compression.

Comment: Close unity, re-open, take out a build, Go to console > small arrow on the top right > Open Editor.Log file > Paste it here. i'll be able to help in a better way with this

Comment: @Brundaveena yes, you can select all videos and change Import settings of all videos simultaneously.